# how to wait for output using Net::OpenSSH and wait for ssh->capture()

Tags: perl, openssh

I do have this script that  ssh to remote host using NET::OpenSSH, then send a command on remote host and capture and put then into array, it works if system is not buys or I should there is not lots of files but if there is many files to match and system is buys then it escape due to the timeout, putting a timeout value is not sufficient as I don't know how much it will take, is there any way  I can get this right..thanks in advance..

```
     use Net::OpenSSH;
     # some code to login to remote host using ssh such $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new()

     my $ls = $ssh->capture({timeout => 1}, "find / -iname '*.pm'");
```

thanks again

Comment: Just use bigger values for the timeouts (i.e. 60 or 120). Most error conditions are detected immediately, so the timeout is just a protection against rare undetected error conditions to ensure that the call eventually finalizes.

Comment: thanks, but it seems timeout do not work, i put 30000 and still after a few seconds it returns nothing, and exited, but when II do it manually it takes say 60 seconds and prints all the result! so so either timeout is not working in this module (capture) or there is something else here, I assume timeout is in sec not ms!

Comment: Set `$Net::OpenSSH::debug = -1` at the beginning of your script and run it again.